# xlsxwriter parentheses added to formula

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I'm using the xlsxwriter python module.
I'm trying to use the 
`.write_formula()` 
function to write a formula into a cell that checks existence of content of a cell in a different sheet:

```
worksheet.write_formula('B1', "=ISBLANK($'jan-18'.A7)")
```

The sheet `jan-18` exists.
However, when I execute this code, a parenthesis is added which causes the formula to not work:

```
=ISBLANK($'jan-18'.A7))
```

I have also experienced a similar problem with another formula where two parentheses are added.  Has anyone experienced something alike?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the wring address? It should be `$'jan-18'!A7)` (the dot is wrong)

Comment: I have the same problem when substituting the dot `.` with an exclamation mark `!`

Comment: Then maybe (that's a long-shot) you're supposed to use single quotation marks? `worksheet.write_formula('B1', '=ISBLANK($\'jan-18\'.A7)')` Don't forget to escape the ones inside the formula!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fully reproducible example shows you how to use the `ISBLANK` Excel function using `.write_formula()` in xlsxwriter.

The key difference seems to be that you're using `.` instead of `!`.

Also your placement of the `$` would be fine like this `.write_formula('B1', "=ISBLANK('jan-18'!$A$7)")`, but not like this `.write_formula('B1', "=ISBLANK($'jan-18'!A7)")`.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('jan-18')
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet1.write('A7', 1)
worksheet2.write_formula('B1', "=ISBLANK('jan-18'!A7)")

workbook.close()
```